# ANTLR parsing Java Properties

Tags: properties, antlr, grammar

I'm trying to pick up ANTLR and writing a grammar for Java Properties.  I'm hitting an issue here and will appreciate some help.

In Java Properties, it has a little strange escape handling.  For example,

```
key1=1=Key1
key\=2==
```

results in key-value pairs in Java runtime as

```
KEY     VALUE
===     =====
key1    1=Key1
key=2   =
```

So far, this is the best I can mimic.. by folding the '=' and value into one single token.

```
grammar Prop;
file : (pair | LINE_COMMENT)* ;
pair : ID VALUE ;
ID  :   (~('='|'\r'|'\n') | '\\=')* ;
VALUE   :   '=' (~('\r'|'\n'))*;
CARRIAGE_RETURN
    :       ('\r'|'\n') + {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
LINE_COMMENT
    : '#' ~('\r'|'\n')* ('\r'|'\n'|EOF)
    ;
```

Is there any good suggestion if I can implement a better one?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You might find that the \-escape mechanism works to put other characters in the key as well, such as key\ name which has a space. Also note that colon (:) and even a space can separate key and values in Java .properties files. Also, there's the trailing \ in the value for continuing values on the next line.

Answer (score 3):

It's not as easy as that. You can't handle much at the lexing level because many things depend on a certain context. So at the lexing level, you can only match single characters and construct key and values in parser rules. Also, the `=` and `:` as possible key-value separators *and* the fact that these characters can be the start of a value, makes them a pain in the butt to translate into a grammar. The easiest would be to include these (possible) separator chars in your value-rule and after matching the separator *and* value together, strip the separator chars from it.

A small demo:

### JavaProperties.g

```
grammar JavaProperties;

parse
  :  line* EOF
  ;

line
  :  Space* keyValue
  |  Space* Comment eol
  |  Space* LineBreak
  ;

keyValue
  :  key separatorAndValue eol
     {
       // Replace all escaped `=` and `:`
       String k = $key.text.replace("\\:", ":").replace("\\=", "=");

       // Remove the  separator, if it exists
       String v = $separatorAndValue.text.replaceAll("^\\s*[:=]\\s*", "");

       // Remove all escaped line breaks with trailing spaces
       v = v.replaceAll("\\\\(\r?\n|\r)[ \t\f]*", "").trim();

       System.out.println("\nkey   : `" + k + "`");
       System.out.println("value : `" + v + "`");
     }
  ;

key
  :  keyChar+
  ;

keyChar
  :  AlphaNum 
  |  Backslash (Colon | Equals)
  ;

separatorAndValue
  :  (Space | Colon | Equals) valueChar+
  ;

valueChar
  :  AlphaNum 
  |  Space 
  |  Backslash LineBreak
  |  Equals
  |  Colon
  ;

eol
  :  LineBreak
  |  EOF
  ;

Backslash : '\\';
Colon     : ':';
Equals    : '=';

Comment
  :  ('!' | '#') ~('\r' | '\n')*
  ;

LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;

Space
  :  ' ' 
  |  '\t' 
  |  '\f'
  ;

AlphaNum
  :  'a'..'z'
  |  'A'..'Z'
  |  '0'..'9'
  ;
```

The grammar above can be tested with the class:

### Main.java

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRFileStream("test.properties");
    JavaPropertiesLexer lexer = new JavaPropertiesLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    JavaPropertiesParser parser = new JavaPropertiesParser(tokens);
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

and the input file:

### test.properties

```
key1 = value 1
        key2:value 2
 key3                  :value3
ke\:\=y4=v\
    a\
    l\
    u\
    e    4
key\=5==
key6           value6
```

to produce the following output:

```
key   : `key1`
value : `value 1`

key   : `key2`
value : `value 2`

key   : `key3`
value : `value3`

key   : `ke:=y4`
value : `value    4`

key   : `key=5`
value : `=`

key   : `key6`
value : `value6`
```

Realize that my grammar is just an example: it does not account for all valid properties files (sometimes backslashes should be ignored, there's no Unicode escapes, many characters are missing in the key and value). For a complete specification of properties files, see:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29

Comment: That code doesn't compile for me with ANTLR 3.3 because it can't find the parse method on JavaPropertiesParser. Was this code meant for ANTLR 3.x?

Comment: @Aaron, it works as I posted it (tested with version 3.3). My guess is you're using a different target than the (default) Java target.

Comment: Fails on antlr 3.5, but like you say, it was written for 3.3. I just wish they wouldn't make major changes in minor revisions. :(